# multiple expression/strings in a query

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help with this script please, I am mere mortal not programmer! only the first string expression is working

Aim is to get orders with the following postcode ranges to assign themselves to a folder
7000-8999
3000-3999
5000-5900

```
String AusPostcodeExp = @"^[78][0-9][0-9][0-9]$";
String AusPostcodeExp2 = @"^3[0-9][0-9][0-9]$";
String AusPostcodeExp3 = @"^5[0-8][0-9][0-9]$";
String AusPostcodeExp4 = @"^5[0-9][0][0]$";
String postcode = order.PostCode.ToString();

if (order.Country.ToUpper() == "AUSTRALIA" && IsValid(postcode, AusPostcodeExp ))
if (order.Country.ToUpper() == "AUSTRALIA" && IsValid(postcode, AusPostcodeExp2 ))
if (order.Country.ToUpper() == "AUSTRALIA" && IsValid(postcode, AusPostcodeExp3 ))
if (order.Country.ToUpper() == "AUSTRALIA" && IsValid(postcode, AusPostcodeExp4 ))
{
order.SetAssignToAFolder("MELBOURNE");
```

Comment: What language is this? Also, your code seems to be missing part of it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is C#, but @Kendall is right. If this is C#, please use include the `[C#]` tag.

Comment: like i said, I am mere mortal, don't know what you mean by [c#] tag!

Comment: @jacquisu I've edited your question to include the C# tag. If this is incorrect, and you're not using C#, you can correct my edit by using the 'edit' link below the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternation (`|`). For example, `A|B` will first attempt to match pattern `A`, and failing that, will then try to match pattern `B`.

You can combine this with other regular expression constructs like groups (`(…)`) and quantifiers (`{…}`) to significantly simplify your pattern.

Try a pattern like this:

```
^([378][0-9]{3}|5([0-8][0-9]{2}|900))$
```

Hopefully, this diagram (generated using [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com)) will help explain what's going on here:

[image: regexper diagram]

Comment: That looked ace, appreciate your help, however tried it and nothing happened!            String AusPostcodeExp = @"^([378][0-9]{3}|5([0-8][0-9]{2}|900))$";
String postcode = order.PostCode.ToString();
if (order.Country.ToUpper() == "AUSTRALIA" && IsValid(postcode, AusPostcodeExp ))

{
order.SetAssignToAFolder("MELBOURNE");  I know my original code is a bit long winded but the first line was working on its own it just doesn't like it when I add the other ranges, I thought maybe I was missing something like an 'else' or should remove the $ sign or something?

Comment: Well the pattern works for me. What's the exact input? (`postalcode`)